# setinterval problems repeating function

Tags: javascript

I want some words to dropdown from the top of my page by applying this function

```
function dropWord(){
  var word = document.createElement("div");
  body.insertBefore(word, document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]);
  word.classList.add("word");
  var random = (Math.random() * (99 - 0)).toFixed(1);
  word.style.left = `${random}%`
}
```

and repeat this function every 3seconds here

```
setInterval(dropWord(), 3000);
```

the function works once then it doesn't proceed, I am certain its some stupid mistake I am doing, any help will be appreciated

Comment: drop the `()` from calling dropword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` expects a function reference. You are actually calling the function. You need this:

```
setInterval(dropWord, 3000); // notice the lack of () in the function
```

Comment: i knew i was missing something small and stupid, thanks! this works now